# SAS: getting the filesize of created DBF file

Tags: stored-procedures, sas, sas-macro

I have SAS stored process that ceates DBF file from SAS data set rr_udf_value and finds its size (F_SIZE):

```
filename dbfout "/SASInside/DBF/myfile";

proc export
   data=rr_udf_value
   outfile=dbfout
   dbms=dbf
   replace;
run; 

%let f_nm=/SASInside/DBF/myfile.DBF;

%let rc=%sysfunc(filename(onefile, &f_nm.));
%let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&onefile));
%let F_SIZE=%sysfunc(finfo(&fid,File Size (bytes)));
%put &F_SIZE;
```

The problem is that the variable F_SIZE is empty in STP log. But if after execution of STP I run commands

```
%let f_nm=/SASInside/DBF/myfile.DBF;

%let rc=%sysfunc(filename(onefile, &f_nm.));
%let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&onefile));
%let F_SIZE=%sysfunc(finfo(&fid,File Size (bytes)));
%put FSIZE=&F_SIZE;
```

manually, everithing is OK: F_SIZE=17342.

Why F_SIZE is not initialized while running STP, and how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any warnings or errors?  Is F_SIZE uninitialized, or blank (these are different)?  When you say manually, is that running on the same server as the STP is with 100% definitely the same permissions (in particular, I wonder if `fopen` requires XCMD)?

Comment: No warnings or erors, but variable fid=0 (it means that fopen fails while running in STP). F_SIZE is blank. I run the program on the same server. STP succesfully creates DBF file, so I think has reuired permissions to check its size. Am I right?

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely talking disk permissions.  Some processes that use shell-like access (ie, `x`, `syscmd`, etc.) are forbidden on server environments by default.  This apparently includes `filename` (see [this article](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-sysop-xcmd.htm) for example.)  So I would either add a check for what the value of `xcmd` option is on your STP server, or talk to your server admin.

Comment: Hey, Joe! Yes ou are right! The problem was in permissions. I switched STP option "Server type" to "Workspace server only" and STP reurned file  size. So, thank ou very much!

Comment: Glad to hear - I've put that as an answer.  (Specifically, the XCMD issue-  which may be your difference here.)  If it's actually related to something slightly different, you should put your own answer with more specifics (as I don't know actually what "Workspace Server Only" does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filename()` is restricted in environments with `OPTION NOXCMD`, which is by default set for server environments.  This is for security reasons (as `XCMD` allows shell access).  You can enable this with by enabling `OPTION XCMD`, though your server admin (if this is not you) would have to enable it on the server and not in your local session typically.

See [the SAS documentation on XCMD](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-sysop-xcmd.htm) for more information.

Comment: I also found that filesize can be obtained with simpler instrucions:  `filename x '/SASInside/DBF/myfile';
proc sql;
select * from dictionary.EXTFILES where Fileref='X';
quit;` and without switching server type.

Comment: @PierreVanStulov Please post that as an answer - and if it solved your problem, accept it!